# How can I rig an SVG humanoid?

Tags: rigging

I have a template SVG file for an articulated doll and it looks something like this:

[image]

I can manually rotate and pose it in Adobe illustrator, but is there a better workflow to rig 2D segmented assets?

Comment: You need to have a runtime for your target because it depends on the underlying system that you're using. You could do it in [blender](https://github.com/ndee85/coa_tools) or [dragon bones](http://dragonbones.com/en/index.html) but note that both have different approaches and output files.

Comment: There definitely are runtime systems for this kind of animation in games, but it's not necessarily required.  You can create sprite sets (sets of images) and play them - an approach that's been used for years in many games.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a tool like Spriter (https://brashmonkey.com/).  It is specifically designed to let you combine components like you have, and create animations from them.

With it or tools like it, you can join your pieces together, then move them about to create poses, or sequences of poses to make an animation.

Here's a video that Brash Monkey has on Spriter that shows how this all works...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrgGhK48Joo

If anyone knows of any other good tools, please feel free to comment.  I happened to know Spriter so that's the one I shared.